# UISwipeGestureRecognizer doesn't always respond. Random

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm new to Xcode.

I have two `UILabel` that randomly change their content. For the change I use a `UISwipegestureRecognizer` and a switch statement.  Why the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` reacts only sporadically?

Thanks for any advice!

.m

```
-(void)questionAndAnswer {

question.hidden = NO;
answer.hidden = NO;

int text = arc4random() % 32;

switch (text) {
    case 0:
        question.text = @"Anlieferung/anliefern";
        answer.text = @"delivery, supply/deliver, supply";

        break;

        //  [...]
```

Comment: Can  you provide some of the code for your `UISwipegestureRecognizer` as well? **What** is calling `questionAndAnswer`?

Comment: Please paste the entire code. All I can see is that you are creating a random int between 0 - 32 and you switch just 0. And please paste your swipe recognizer as it is most likely there something is wrong